# Definition of Thrilla with Vanilla

Tags: meaning

A foreign student asked me (her teacher) what THRILLA WITH VANILLA meant. I haven't the slightest idea and when I go to Google, the only reference is the Romney-Obama debate, as though the expression was just invented for this purpose. Can anyone help define this (preferably out of this political context)?

Comment: Are you sure they didn't mean "Thrilla in Manila" … the Ali vs. Frazier boxing match?

Comment: @tajmo: It's also possible that "Thrilla with Vanilla" is a loose pun on "Thrilla in Manila". That seems likely if the only refernce to this phrase is in the context of the debate. Maybe the "with Vanilla" part is a refernce to skin colours of the participants?

Answer (score 9):

*Thrilla with Vanilla* is certainly a play on words based on the Ali-Frazier *[Thrilla in Manilla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrilla_in_Manila)* which followed the Ali-Foreman *[Rumble in the Jungle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rumble_in_the_Jungle)*.

You have picked up the use by [Jonah Goldberg in National Review](http://www.nationalreview.com/articles/283245/debates-newt-gingrich-s-real-target-obama-jonah-goldberg#) in 2011: he seems to be suggesting an Obama-Romney debate would be dull because of Romney lacks personality.  It may also suggest at least one of the individuals has white skin.

It has been used before, in the promotion of a March 2002 [celebrity boxing match involving Rob Van Winkle](http://espn.go.com/page2/s/celebbox/020314.html) (previously known as Vanilla Ice).

The less distorted *Thrilla in Vanilla* seems to be more common: for example it was used in 2009 to describe the [Texas gubernatorial race](http://www.texasmonthly.com/2009-02-01/feature.php), a [US Senate hearing unlikely to produce disagreements](http://michellemalkin.com/2009/04/24/the-thrilla-in-vanilla/) and as a title of an [adult film](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1587287/)  as well as being used for various food and drink concoctions.

Comment: One of Mohammed Ali's many unapprecaited contributions to the English Language.